# Django i18n External Redirect security issue

Tags: django, security, internationalization, owasp, zap

(I'm new with Django)

I ran an automated scan (OWASP ZAP) to test my application security and it's returning a high risk flag for External Redirect:

[Automated Scan Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftzJN.png)

Looks like it's something to do with the path "/i18n/setlang/" and the parameter "next", like "?next=(redirect)"

I set the i18n path like that

```
urlpatterns = [ path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')), ... ]
```

And this is my HTML

```
        <div class="flex justify-items-end">
           {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
           {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
           {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}

           {% for language in languages %}
              <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" id="form_{{ language.code }}" style="display:inline!important;">
              {% csrf_token %}
                 <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
                 <input name="language" type="hidden" value="{{ language.code }}" />
              </form>
              <button class="lang-button" type="submit" form="form_{{ language.code }}" value="Submit">
                 {% if language.code == "en" %}
                 <img src="{% static 'assets/webfonts/gb.svg' %}" width="30" alt="gb" class="rounded-lg h-5 w-5 mr-3  hover:opacity-75" />
                 {% endif %}
                 {% if language.code == "es" %}
                 <img src="{% static 'assets/webfonts/es.svg' %}" width="30" alt="gb" class="rounded-lg h-5 w-5 hover:opacity-75" />
                 {% endif %}
                 {% if language.code == "pt" %}
                 <img src="{% static 'assets/webfonts/br.svg' %}" width="30" alt="gb" class="rounded-lg h-5 w-5 mr-3  hover:opacity-75" />
                 {% endif %}
              </button>
           {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

I don't know if it's really a security issue because it says at the end of the report description that "URL redirectors do not necessarily represent a direct security vulnerability but can be abused by attackers trying to social engineer victims into believing that they are navigating to a site other than the true destination"

What should I do? :(

Comment: I do not see the risk from what you posted: the redirect target `redirect_to` is controlled by the server and put inside a hidden input field and the form is secured by a csrf token. That should be good enough, I think. (Disclaimer: there may be other parts on your page that you did not show). An alternative would be to store the redirect_to inside the server's session instead.

Comment: "hiding" a parameter doesn't prevent an attacker from abusing it. It's still a value that can be controlled.

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't provided enough specific to be 100% sure my educated guess would be that you aren't validating/restricting the value of `next` at all. So when ZAP set `next=SomeRandomNumber.owasp.org` your app accepted it and the user is subsequently redirected to https://SomeRandomNumber.owasp.org

Comment: do you know how can I do that?